# converting string splitter tvf w/cte to filtered scaler Function

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to split 30,000 addresses. This is so I can to some specific matching with a couple other lists of similar size. I found code that works great, but needed to get a specific single field instead of a table returned.

From this code:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.Split (@sep char(1), @s varchar(512))
RETURNS table
AS
RETURN (
    WITH Pieces(pn, start, stop) AS (
      SELECT 1, 1, CHARINDEX(@sep, @s)
      UNION ALL
      SELECT pn + 1, stop + 1, CHARINDEX(@sep, @s, stop + 1)
      FROM Pieces
      WHERE stop > 0
    )
    SELECT pn,
      SUBSTRING(@s, start, CASE WHEN stop > 0 THEN stop-start ELSE 512 END) AS s
    FROM Pieces
  )
```

After many attempts, I ended with this modified code:

```
USE [AddrTools]
GO

/****** Object:  UserDefinedFunction [dbo].[fnGetPart]    Script Date: 5/4/2016 1:23:33 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

create function [dbo].[fnGetAddrPart]
(
@sep as char(1),
@iPart as int,
@sFullAddr as varchar(200),
@iPartCnt as int
)
returns varchar(30)
as
Begin

declare @sPart as varchar(30)

set @sep = ' '

;
with Pieces(pn, start, stop) AS 
(
      SELECT 1, 1, CHARINDEX(@sep, @sFullAddr)
      UNION ALL
      SELECT pn + 1, stop + 1, CHARINDEX(@sep, @sFullAddr, stop + 1)
      FROM Pieces
      WHERE stop > 0
    )
set @sPart =
(
SELECT 
    SUBSTRING(@sFullAddr, start, CASE WHEN stop > 0 THEN stop-start ELSE 512 END) AS s
    FROM Pieces
    where pn = @iPart
)
return(@sPart)
end

GO
```

And I get this error:

> Msg 444, Level 16, State 2, Procedure fnGetAddrPart, Line 27
>   Select statements included within a function cannot return data to a client.

Also, the hover error on the first red underlined code is on set of set `@spart`.

> Incorrect syntax need 'set'

Can anyone help me through this?

Comment: Can't you just use your original function and use a where clause on the value of pn?

Comment: Honestly your table valued function could be helped. But moving this to a scalar function is a bad idea. Scalar functions are horribly inefficient. Here is a great article on the topic of splitting strings. http://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings One thing that all these splitters lack however is a way to get a specific row by position. Here is an article to the splitter that I prefer. It does have this ability with no effort. http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/

Comment: going to links now  THANKS!

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the proper syntax for the last query is more like this:

```
SELECT @sPart =
    SUBSTRING(@sFullAddr, start, CASE WHEN stop > 0 THEN stop-start ELSE 512 END) AS s
    FROM Pieces
    where pn = @iPart
```

That should get past the Msg 444 error.